# Compiling Kamailio modules from source results in error

Tags: c, lua, kamailio

I have *Kamailio* version `5.5.2` source code and I am trying to compile *Lua* module (`app_lua.so`) to be included. However, running **make all** command results in a following error for that module:

```
CC (gcc) [M app_lua.so]     app_lua_api.o
app_lua_api.c:1942:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'luaL_openlib' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        luaL_openlib(L, "KSR", _sr_crt_KSRMethods, 0);
        ^
app_lua_api.c:1942:2: note: did you mean 'luaL_openlibs'?
/usr/local/include/lua/lualib.h:49:18: note: 'luaL_openlibs' declared here
LUALIB_API void (luaL_openlibs) (lua_State *L);
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Any suggestions? I do have *Lua* installed, it is version `5.4.3`.

-- update --
Just tried older `app_lua_sr` package, same error persists there as well.

Comment: use -DLUA_COMPAT_MODULE when compiling app_lua_api.c

Answer (score 0):

Lua 5.4.x is not supported by Kamailio at this moment. Lua 5.4.x changed the embedding API, becoming incompatible with older ones. Try with Lua 5.2.x, I think 5.3.x works also because it defines compatibility mode by checking the version (*pkg-config* is required).